# saving Manipulate data inside a notebook

Tags: manipulate

I want to send a few `Manipulate` `Plots` and regular `plots` to my advisor in a notebook. I typically `Import` data into my notebook to generate plots but when I open my file on a new computer, the regular `Plots` stay but the `Manipulate` ones are dead, until I `Import` the data again. Is there any way I can keep the data inside the notebook so when he "enables dynamic" to open the notebook on his computer, that the `Manipulate` `plots` become active, just the way the data in regular `plots` are not lost ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SaveDefinitions` would work for you I guess.

Try the below code. Execute, then save the notebook it is in. Kill the kernel with `Quit[]` and reopen the notebook. Content is still there and is manipulable without re-executing.

```
f = ExampleData[{"Text", "GettysburgAddress"}];

Manipulate[
 ListPlot[(StringLength /@ StringSplit[f])[[;; ;; i]]],
 {i, 1, 5, 1},
 SaveDefinitions -> True
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: In my experience, `SaveDefinitions` is not as reliable as `Initialization`, particularly when moving between platforms.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries and Mark McClure. Thanks for both your answers. Since I had to accept one, I went with Sjoreds. Right now I am using `SaveDefinitions` but when I have to make an important presentation, I will not take a chance and use `Initialization`.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `Initialization` option of `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[DateListPlot[data[[1 ;; k]],
  Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> {0, 40}],
  {{k, 10}, 1, Length[data], 1},
  Initialization :> (data = FinancialData["FB", All])]
```

Alternatively, you could store the data in a separate initialization cell.  That is create a cell like so:

```
Manipulate[DateListPlot[data[[1 ;; k]],
  Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> {0, 40}],
  {{k, 10}, 1, Length[data], 1}]
```

And create (anywhere in the notebook) a separate initialization cell like so:

```
data = FinancialData["FB", All]
```

Note that this initialization could contain the pre-downloaded data, rather than an import type command.  The important issue is that it's cell properties be set to be an initialization cell.

Comment: Using an initialization cell in your alternative method a `Dynamic` will throw errors until that `Initialization` cell is evaluated. The only way I've found around this is to set your notebook to evaluate automatically at open.

Comment: @kale That sounds believable. For that method, I was envisioning a scenario where the notebook is opened with no `Output` cells - the user could then execute the `Input` cells to see the output. The point behind the initialization cell would be to contain long input, such as pre-imported data.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Thanks a lot for your answer. I used the `SaveDefinitions` right now and picked it as the accepted answer because that seemed simpler but I will now try your cell initialization method. I'm sorry, I can't believe that it has taken me 8 days to respond. Thanks a lot.